# Interpreting output of models with categorical variables in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, interpretation, biostatistics

I have a data set that contains coral reef data- count of fish (C_TOTAL), the habitat complexity measurement rugosity (RUGOSITY), and the area of the reef that the data was collected at (ZONE- 5 levels: crest, mid flat, inner flat, outer flat, slope). Here's my data:

```r
structure(list(ZONE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("CREST", "INNER_FLAT", "MID_FLAT", 
"OUTER_FLAT", "SLOPE"), class = "factor"), C_TOTAL = c(8L, 28L, 
24L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 75L, 21L, 60L, 44L, 7L, 20L, 31L, 
12L, 33L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 10L, 23L, 81L, 37L, 89L, 14L, 0L, 4L, 
6L, 16L, 33L, 7L, 6L, 42L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 21L, 35L, 71L, 2L, 3L, 
1L), RUGOSITY = c(1.4965238288, 1.4965238288, 1.4965238288, 1.1062247641, 
1.1062247641, 1.1062247641, 1.1970543221, 1.1970543221, 1.1970543221, 
1.2099143375, 1.2099143375, 1.2099143375, 1.6942220379, 1.6942220379, 
1.6942220379, 1.8957308013, 1.8957308013, 1.8957308013, 1.1495742454, 
1.1495742454, 1.1495742454, 1.185265051, 1.185265051, 1.185265051, 
1.28199262, 1.28199262, 1.28199262, 1.7299341139, 1.7299341139, 
1.7299341139, 1.6104336966, 1.6104336966, 1.6104336966, 1.1425662435, 
1.1425662435, 1.1425662435, 1.1788409644, 1.1788409644, 1.1788409644, 
1.3124270773, 1.3124270773, 1.3124270773, 1.521531149, 1.521531149, 
1.521531149)), row.names = c(NA, 45L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am looking to model if rugosity has an effect on fish abundance. I am using a negative binomial distribution with a sqrt link:

```r
require(MASS)
mod <- glm.nb(C_TOTAL ~ RUGOSITY + ZONE, 
              data=majordf, link=sqrt)
```

When I run the model summary, this is what I get:

All covariates are being compared to the CREST level of the ZONE covariate. I am confused on how to interpret these results, as from what I understand right now I can only compare the effect of the rest of the covariates to that of the effect that crest has on fish abundance- which is not helpful in determining if rugosity has an effect on fish abundance. Can anyone help?

Comment: The slope for Rugosity is significant. Since you did not fit an interaction between Rugosity and Zone, the model assumes the slope for Rugosity applies to all Zones.

Comment: Any reason why you prefer the square root link?